# components in accordion panel tab title facet

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

We are facing an issue with using components inside an accordionPanel tab header.
Basically we have a dropdown and a button within the title facet of the accordionPanel's tab.

Clicking on the dropdown or button collapses the containing accordion tab,
also the button click does not call the listener methods, instead just collapses the panel.
Tried wrapping the dropdown and button in a h:panelGrid but it doesn't help.

We are using primefaces 3.5. I saw that title faces support has been added
[here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3503) but the button and dropdown click does not work. Here is a sample code

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{errorTips.classificationList}" var="i"
                    activeIndex="" dynamic="true">
                    <p:tab>
                       <f:facet name="title">  
                          <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="2" width="100%" >
                          <h:outputText value="#{i.errorValue} - #{i.errorCount}"/> 

                          <p:selectOneMenu id="prop16" value="#{errorTips.classValue}"
                                effect="fade" style="width:100px;">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{errorTips.classValues}" />
                          </p:selectOneMenu>

                          <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{errorTips.saveClassCategory}" update="tabView">
                          </p:commandButton>

                          <p:commandButton value="Export" actionListener="#{errorTips.exportTask}">
                          </p:commandButton>
                          </h:panelGrid>
</p:commandButton>
                                        </h:panelGrid>
                                </f:facet>
```

Are we doing something wrong or is this a primefaces bug?
Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance!
Andy

Comment: Your JSF code is invalid. There is a part missing or you simply have unclosed tags.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, I have checked -  there is no unclosed tags, else it would have given jsf compilation errors. Can you please explain what you mean by part missing?

Comment: I only meant the code you posted. `accordionPanel` and `tab` are unclosed, last `commandButton` and `panelGrid` are closed twice.